# Psycopg2 --- Inserting an array

Tags: python, arrays, psycopg2

I have an array of variables (`arr`) that I would like to insert into my database, where I am using Psycopg2. The array I am inserting has 45 entries. The code I am running right now is the following:

```
string = ''
for i in range(0, length):
    string = string + "%s, "
string = string[:-2]

query = """
    INSERT INTO schema.tablename
    VALUES (%s)"""
query = query.replace("%s", string)
cur.execute(query, (arr, ))
```

I want to avoid writing the columns explicitly as the table I am working with may change (add columns/remove columns). The code above gives me the error:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [`executemany`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany) function?

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO table VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", tup)
```

Comment: /facedesk
Thank you! That did exactly what I was looking for.